# Bootstrap wrap the whole word after containing hyphen inside the text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

wrap whole word which contains hyphens like 12-02-2018  but not wrap partial word
      like  12-02-
            2018

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Test test Test test Test test Test test 12-02-2018</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use additional span, something like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Test test Test test Test test Test test <span class="text-nowrap">12-02-2018</span></p>
</div>
```

it is equals to

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Test test Test test Test test Test test <span style="white-space: nowrap">12-02-2018</span></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok thanks..but i am getting this string from server end.so how can i insert html tags at server side response.it also working if i put &nbsp;&nbsp in response;

Comment: use client side scripting: javascript. It is absolutely legal.